# whats the best way to play audio on all browsers?

Tags: html, html5-audio

I'm having a nightmare trying to get `<audio> ... </audio>` to work on all browsers. I have to include ogg and mp3 and wav files to get one file to show up in ever browser. Is there an easier way, that is html5 looking? I haven't looked into any jquery libraries or anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try, **Audio.JS**, it is a nice package for audio playback...

**audio.js** is a drop-in javascript library that allows HTML5’s  tag to be used anywhere.

**[Link to Audio.js](http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/)**

Comment: the media on that page doesn't even play in my own chrome browser 
http://prntscr.com/xvywo

Comment: i am using v25 of chrome, this plugin works for v7+ chrome what are you using??